# Why is Outlook AppointmentItem.Parent throwing an exception?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, add-in

Can someone explain me what am i doing wrong here?

Shouldn't the Item.Parent return a folder?

[image]

Comment: Does it definitely have a parent?

Comment: It is a valid appointment so it has a calendar parent...

Comment: How do you retreive that appointment?

Comment: I restarted the whole project and reviewed the whole code. Although i couldn't realize what the issue was, the problem was solved. Thank you anyway!